# How to install phpUnit in Symfony4 / Symfony5?

Tags: composer-php, symfony4

When I install phpUnit directly with `composer req phpunit/phpunit` I get a warning message:

```
Adding phpunit/phpunit as a dependency is discouraged
in favor of Symfony's PHPUnit Bridge.

  * Instead:
    1. Remove it now: composer remove --dev phpunit/phpunit
    2. Use Symfony's bridge: composer require --dev phpunit
```

So I do as the message says, but after `composer require --dev phpunit` it installs the `symfony/test-pack` which only install the Panther and the phpUnit bridge, but the phpUnit itself is nowhere to be seen.

How to install phpUnit in Symfony4 properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` script by accident, and turns out it downloads the phpUnit library locally when executed.